# How to access customers in a customer group using Shopify API with rails gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, shopify

I am using the Shopify API gem in my rails app to access customers and orders.

I can pull down Customer Groups fine like below and all working well.

```
ShopifyAPI::CustomerGroup.find
```

I know want to access customers within a customer group, using the API call  **/admin/customer_groups/#{id}/customers.json**

How do I do this in the same format as I do for the groups (i.e. using the Shopify API gem)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE: Version 3.0.3 of the [shopify_api gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/shopify_api) adds a `customers` method to CustomerGroup that fetches all customers for that group.

You can now do things like this:

```
  group = ShopifyAPI::CustomerGroup.find(123)
  customers = group.customers
```

--

Right now you have to do this:

```
Customer.find(:all, :params => {:customer_group_id => customer_group.id})
```

Where customer_group is the one you retrieved from your earlier call.

HOWEVER. I've just added a pull request to the shopify_api repo that encapsulates this call in a `customers` method on the `CustomerGroup` resource directly. Once it gets approved you'll be able to call `.customers` on any customer group you have and it'll give you all the customers.

Here's the pull request for reference: https://github.com/Shopify/shopify_api/pull/40

Comment: Hi David, I can not get the above code to work,updated the gem to 3.0.3 but getting an error, please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13408740/uninitialized-constant-shopifyapicustomergroupcustomers-error