# uninitialized constant ShopifyAPI::CustomerGroup::Customers error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, shopify

No doubt I am doing something wrong here, but I am following instructions on a new commit from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13398762/how-to-access-customers-in-a-customer-group-using-shopify-api-with-rails-gem).

I am getting the following error

```
uninitialized constant ShopifyAPI::CustomerGroup::Customers
00:33:56 web.1    | /Users/matt/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/shopify_api-3.0.3/lib/shopify_api/resources/customer_group.rb:4:in `customers''
```

When running this code

```
 group = ShopifyAPI::CustomerGroup.find(5614012)
            customers = group.customers
```

Here is the [gem file](https://github.com/Shopify/shopify_api/blob/master/lib/shopify_api/resources/customer_group.rb) mentioned above

Comment: I think this question is a continuation of the one you asked in question you linked above (it's probably best to just continue the question on the same thread rather than asking a new one).  Anyway, the response there says that `group.customers` will not work on the 3.0.3 version of the gem (but that it will in a later version once a pending pull request is merged).  Try it with the pending pull request fork referenced in the answer.

Comment: The updated answer on there implies that version 3.0.3 does support that though?

Comment: Also just found out this code does not work, it ignores the customer group filter and bring back all customers.  `Customer.find(:all, :params => {:customer_group_id => customer_group.id})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Version 3.0.3 should solve the problem, I'll have to look into why it isn't.

In the meantime, the following will do what you want:

```
group = ShopfiyAPI::CustomerGroup.find(123)
customers = group.get(:customers)
```

Comment: Thanks David. With `group.get(:customers)` is there anyway to access the count function to get the no of customer in that group? Helps with managing the fetch process and API limits. For exmaple what if that group had 3,000 customers and we are I assume limited to 250 records per API call

Comment: I am still getting a uninitialized constant with the new code you suggested above...

Comment: What's the full error? Where's the uninitialized constant occurring?

Comment: OK the error was my fault, sorry. But how do your recommend dealing with groups which have thousands of customers, how do I page through the results?